# Proof that the sum of two Gaussian variables is another Gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions

*The sum of two Gaussian variables is another Gaussian.*
It seems natural, but I could not find a proof using Google.

What's a short way to prove this?
Thanks!

Edit: Provided the two variables are independent.

Comment: What search terms were you using? I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) as the top result on Google.

Comment: Please make sure to use well-defined terms and more appropriate tags.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that one, indeed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables Thanks Kaestur Hakarl!

Comment: @Nicholas: You need to mention that the two variables are independent, otherwise it's not true (if X is N(0,1), then so is Y=-X, but their sum X+Y=0 is not normally distributed).

Comment: @Simon +1 indeed thanks! I edit the question.

Comment: @SimonNickerson Do you have another counterexample? Since $0 = \delta_0 = \mathcal N(0,0)$ in law. So, the sum of $X$ and $-X$ is still normal, though degenerate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prepared the following as an answer to a question which happened to 
close just as I was putting the finishing touches on my work.  I posted it as a different (self-answered) question but following suggestions from Srivatsan Narayanan and Mike Spivey, I am putting it here and deleting my so-called question.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard Gaussian random variables, what is
the cumulative distribution function of $\alpha X + \beta Y$?

Let $Z = \alpha X + \beta Y$.  We assume without loss of generality that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive real numbers since if, say, $\alpha < 0$, then we can replace $X$ by $-X$ and $\alpha$ by $\vert\alpha\vert$. Then, the cumulative probability distribution function of $Z$ is
$$
F_Z(z) = P\{Z \leq z\} = P\{\alpha X + \beta Y \leq z\} = \int\int_{\alpha x + \beta y \leq z} \phi(x)\phi(y) dx dy
$$
where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the unit Gaussian density function. But, since the integrand $(2\pi)^{-1}\exp(-(x^2 + y^2)/2)$ has circular symmetry, the value of the integral depends only on the distance of the origin from the line $\alpha x + \beta y = z$.
 Indeed, by a rotation of coordinates, we can write
the integral as
$$
F_Z(z) = \int_{x=-\infty}^d \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\phi(y) dx dy
= \Phi(d)
$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard Gaussian cumulative distribution function.
But, 
$$d = \frac{z}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}}$$
and thus the cumulative distribution function of $Z$ is that of a zero-mean Gaussian random variable with variance $\alpha^2 + \beta^2$.

Comment: I like this proof very much, because it explicitly uses the rotational symmetry, and therefore makes it clear why the Gaussian has this property but other distributions do not.

Comment: @DilipSarwate How is $\Phi(d)$ defined? Should it just be $\phi(d)$?

Comment: $\Phi(\cdot)$ is commonly used to denote the standard Gaussian cumulative probability distribution function (CDF), and what I have written is correct; $F_Z(z)$, which is a CDF, is not equal to $\phi(d)$, which is a pdf, as you seem to think.

Comment: what exactly is the rotation ? I missed this step, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I posted the following in response to a question that got closed as a duplicate of this one:

It looks from your comment as if the meaning of your question is different from what I thought at first.  My first answer assumed you knew that the sum of independent normals is itself normal.

You have
$$
\exp\left(-\frac12 \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^2 \right) \exp\left(-\frac12 \left(\frac{z-x}{\beta}\right)^2 \right)
= \exp\left(-\frac12 \left( \frac{\beta^2x^2 + \alpha^2(z-x)^2}{\alpha^2\beta^2} \right) \right).
$$
Then the numerator is
$$
\begin{align}
& (\alpha^2+\beta^2)x^2 - 2\alpha^2 xz + \alpha^2 z^2 \\  \\
= {} & (\alpha^2+\beta^2)\left(x^2 - 2\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2} xz\right) + \alpha^2 z^2 \\  \\
= {} & (\alpha^2+\beta^2)\left(x^2 - 2\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2} xz + \frac{\alpha^4}{(\alpha^2+\beta^2)^2}z^2\right) + \alpha^2 z^2 - \frac{\alpha^4}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}z^2 \\  \\
= {} & (\alpha^2+\beta^2)\left(x - \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}z\right)^2 + \alpha^2 z^2 - \frac{\alpha^4}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}z^2,
\end{align}
$$
and then remember that you still have the $-1/2$ and the $\alpha^2\beta^2$ in the denominator, all inside the "exp" function.

(What was done above is *completing the square*.)

The factor of $\exp\left(\text{a function of }z\right)$ does not depend on $x$ and so is a "constant" that can be pulled out of the integral.

The remaining integral does not depend on "$z$" for a reason we will see below, and thus becomes part of the normalizing constant.

If $f$ is any probability density function, then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x - \text{something}) \; dx
$$
does not depend on "something", because one may write $u=x-\text{something}$ and then $du=dx$, and the bounds of integration are still $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, so the integral is equal to $1$.

Now look at
$$
\alpha^2z^2 - \frac{\alpha^4}{\alpha^2+\beta^2} z^2 = \frac{z^2}{\frac{1}{\beta^2} + \frac{1}{\alpha^2}}.
$$

This was to be divided by $\alpha^2\beta^2$, yielding
$$
\frac{z^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}=\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}\right)^2.
$$
So the density is
$$
(\text{constant})\cdot \exp\left( -\frac12 \left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}\right)^2 \right) .
$$
Where the standard deviation belongs we now have $\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Proof_using_convolutions)?

Comment: I may be the author of that.  It depends on whether, and how much, others may have edited that in recent years.

Comment: From the wikipedia history page: *"cumulative density" is an idiotic self-contradictory phrase*... Nice!

Comment: @The I disagree with that sentiment. It's not like all terminology in math makes a lot of sense. And I somehow always remember it cumulative density, but in my defense I just thought of it as some  "cumulative of the density". :-)

Comment: @Sri : I just thought it quotable. You'll have to consult the author (who is notiffied already)!

Comment: "Cumulative of the density" makes a lot more sense than "cumulative density".  The word "cumulative" contradicts the word "density", so anyone who writes that either isn't paying attention or has not understood the words.

Comment: @Michael Hardy  The Wikipedia link (posted by Didier Piau) which you might have authored at some time in the past says "If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables that are normally distributed (not necessarily jointly so), then ....."  But if the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$ are normal, and they are independent, then their joint density is the product of the marginal densities and so _is_ a jointly normal density, isn't it?  Am I missing a counterexample showing that it is possible to have independent normal random variables that are not jointly normal?

Comment: @Dilip, you are right and the parenthesis you quote is a typo.

Comment: In the context of statistics, acronym CDF denotes Cumulative Distribution Function (here, D isn't for density);  and PDF denotes Probability Density Function.