# If X~N(0,1) and Y~N(0,1) then X+Y~N(0,2)

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to show that 
If X~N(0,1) and Y~N(0,1) then X+Y~N(0,2), where X and Y are independent random variables.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also [The sum of n independent normal random variables.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/238576)

Comment: Think about the mean of $X+Y$, and the variance of $X+Y$.