# Sum of Gaussian Variables may not Gaussian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I am currently trying to understand the following three points which we discussed in lectures recently:

1. We say that $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_d)$ is $d$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian distributed if $X\sim N(\mu,Q)$ for some $\mu\in\mathbb R^d$, $Q=(q_{ij})\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$, that is, $X_i\sim N(\mu_i, q_{ii})$ and $\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)=q_{ij}$.
2. There holds: $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_d)$ is $p$-dimensional multi-variate Gaussian distributed if and only if any linear combination of $X_1,\ldots,X_d$ is Gaussian.
3. If $X,Y$ are Gaussian variables, then $X+Y$ is not be Gaussian (in general). This only holds true if $X,Y$ are indepenent.

---

I get the feeling that the "multivariate Gaussian" definition in point (1) is somewhat wrong (or incomplete), because otherwise (2) and (3) would contradict each other. But (2) seems correct (as I have found it in many other lecture notes online) and (3) seems correct as well (because of Simon Nickerson's comment in [Proof that the sum of two Gaussian variables is another Gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228/proof-that-the-sum-of-two-gaussian-variables-is-another-gaussian)).

I know there are other definitions for "multivariate Gaussian", which do not contradict (2) and (3), but I am basically wondering whether there is any way of fixing the definition I have got, or is it just plain wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no contradiction. "$X$,$Y$ are Gaussian variables" is *not* equivalent to "$(X,Y)$ is Gaussian".

What is true is: if $X_1,X_2$ are *jointly Gaussian* (or, equivalently, if $(X_1,X_2)$ is a 2-dimensional Gaussian), then $X_1 + X_2$ (or any linear combination) is Gaussian.

Now, to say that each of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is a Gaussian variable, only implies that the multivariate variable $(X_1,X_2)$ has some joint distribution, with the property that each marginal is Gaussian. This does *not* imply that they are jointly Gaussian.

Point 3 is correct but slightly misleading. It should really say: "This only holds true if $X,Y$ are jointly Gaussian (independence is just a particular case)"

For example: let $Z_1,Z_2$ be two iid $N(0,1)$ gaussians. Let $X_1=Z_1$, $X_2= \operatorname{sgn}(Z_1) |Z_2|$. Check that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both Gaussian, but $(X_1,X_2)$ is not gaussian. And check that $Y=X_1+X_2$ is not Gaussian (its density at $Y=0$ is zero).

---

Edited: point 1 can indeed be confusing. What follows "that is..." is not part of the definition, but a consequence: *if* $X$ is $d$-dimensional Gaussian with this and that parameter, then each component $X_i$ is also gaussian in itself, with these and those paramenters; but the converse is not true.

To make point 1 a real definition one could say: $X$ is $d$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian distributed if
$X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,Q)$ for some
$\mu\in\mathbb R^d$, and $Q=(q_{ij})\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ positive definite. And by $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,Q)$ we mean that its density is: $$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi |Q|^n}} \exp \left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^t Q^{-1}(x-\mu)}{2}\right)$$

An alternative constructive definition would be:  $X$ is $d$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian is there exists some linear transformation $Z=AX+b$ that results in a set of $d$ iid $\mathcal N(0,1)$ variables.

Comment: The contradiction I see is: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be any two Gaussian variables, i.e. $X_1\sim N(a,b)$, $X_2\sim N(c,d)$ for some $a,b,c,d$. So according to point 1 we have that $X=(X_1,X_2)$ is a multivariate Gaussian distribution. So by point 2, any liner combination is Gaussian, in particular $X_1+X_2$, but then point 3 becomes meaningless. Hence my question, is there anything wrong with point 1? :/

Comment: I see, I added some clarification.