# The sum of normally distributed random variables.

Tags: probability

Let $X_{i}\sim N(\mu_{i} ,\sigma^{2}_{i}), 1 \leq i \leq n$, denote $n$ normally 
distributed independent random variables. I want to show that $$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim N\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_{i},\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_{i}^{2}\right),$$
*without using* convolution integrals or characteristic functions.

Comment: To note your notation is confused, first you use variance $\sigma_i^2$ and then standard deviation $\sigma_i$. Then your claim is wrong if the random variables are not independent. Why to show it without characteristic functions?

Comment: I find his notation strangely artificial. Seriously, why not simply write $\sum_i X_i$ ?

Comment: I corrected those errors. I want to know if there are other methods of proof.

Comment: Other methods than characyeristic function? Showit by direct calculation, using the convolution formula, and maybe induction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that normal distributions are **determined by their moments**,
meaning that if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and
$\mathbb E[X^k]=\mathbb E[Y^k]$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$,
then $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Looking at the simple example $X_1+X_2$ with $X_1\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2),$
for every $k\in\mathbb N$,
one could show (using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) in the second step)
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\Big[\big((X_1+X_2)-(\mu_1+\mu_2)\big)^k\Big]&=\mathbb E\Big[\big((X_1-\mu_1)+(X_2-\mu_2)\big)^k\Big]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[{k\choose t}\sum_{t=0}^k(X_1-\mu_1)^t(X_2-\mu_2)^{k-t}\right]\\
&\cdots\text{ (additional work)}\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if $k$ is odd; and}\\
(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)^k(k-1)!!&\text{if $k$ is even.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
(Where "!!" denotes the [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).)
This implies that $(X_1+X_2)-(\mu_1+\mu_2)\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$,
i.e.,
$X_1+X_2\sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$.

The rest follows from induction.

---

**EDIT:** as [@ki3i](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/202257/ki3i) correctly notes in his comment,
the "standard" proof of the fact that normal distributions are determined by their moments uses the moment generating function.
In fact,
I can't think of a way to prove this without using the moment generating function at this moment.

If you also disallow using the moment generating function *in disguise*,
which wouldn't be surprising if you disallow the use of characteristic functions,
you could compute the CDF of $X_1+X_2$ by
$$F_{X_1+X_2}(z)=\int\int_{[x+y\leq z]}f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(y)~dxdy,$$
where $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$ are the density functions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively.

The solution to this,
which can be a little tedious and involves a bit of trickery,
is written in detail on the wikipedia article [Sum of normally distributed random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) (see the section Geometric proof) as well as [this](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Eisenberg12-0825740.pdf) mathematics magazine article (see "the rotation proof" section).

Comment: @PierreYvesGaudreauLai , This looks nice. But, why isn't this an application of "characteristic functions/Moment Generating functions" in disguise?

Comment: @PierreYvesGaudreauLai , Thanks for addressing my concern and the  helpful references.

Answer (score 1):

The means part is straightforward to show using the *linearity of expectation*; no convolutions or characteristic functions are needed. So, for ease in calculation, 
we can take the $X_i$ to be zero-mean normal random variables and just show that
$\sum_i X_i \sim N\left(0,\sum_i \sigma_i^2\right)$.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal random variables. Then, as
described in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/65871/15941),
$\alpha X + \beta Y$ is a zero-mean normal random variable with variance
$\alpha^2+\beta^2$. This proof is based purely on a rotation of axes; no convolutions or characteristic functions are involved.  But, $\alpha X$ and
$\beta Y$ are zero-mean normal random variables with variances $\alpha^2$
and $\beta^2$ respectively. So, we have that $X_1+X_2 \sim N(0,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$, and as Pierre said, the general result $\sum_i X_i \sim N\left(0,\sum_i \sigma_i^2\right)$ follows by induction. Look, Ma! No convolutions and
no characteristic functions.

Comment: :-) Very nice use of symmetry here: especially the choice of coordinate through the origin, parallel to the plane of interest! I find this quite enlightening.

Comment: @Pierre Yves Graudeau Lan Please what is the additional work.