# Calculate PDF of random variable $Z = X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, gaussian

Suppose you would like to measure a signal, which can be modelled as a Gaussian random variable with $1.0V$ mean and $0.2V$ standard deviation. If you measure this signal with your instrument, it will be subject to the instrument noise and the measured signal will be sum of the noise and the signal. Noise of your instrument can also be modelled as a Gaussian random variable with $0.1V$ mean and $0.1V$ standard deviation.

Write out exact expression to represent the pdf of the measured signal $Z$

My attempt:

Let $X$ represent the random variable for signal & $Y$ represent the random variable for noise then the measured signal $Z$ is given by:

$Z = X+Y$

To find PDF of $Z$, we first find $CDF$ and then take the derivative of it to get the PDF

$CDF$ is given by:

$F_Z(z)=F_Z(Z\leq z)=F_Z(X+Y\leq z)$

I don't know how to go further. Any help and guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? If so then $Z=X+Y$ has normal distribution.

Comment: @drhab it is not mentioned in the question whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Comment: Probably they are meant to be independent. If not then you need the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. That has not been given to you (which makes you powerless). If that is a normal distribution then again $X+Y$ has normal distribution, but you need covariance of $X,Y$ to find the parameters of this distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that signal $X$ and noise $Y$ are independent, then the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of $Z=X+Y$ is
$$\phi_Z(\omega)=\mathbb{E}[e^{i\omega Z}]$$
from which we can compute
$$\phi_Z(\omega)=\mathbb{E}[e^{i\omega (X+Y)}]\underbrace{=}_{\textrm{indep.}}\mathbb{E}[e^{i\omega X}]\mathbb{E}[e^{i\omega Y}]=\phi_X(\omega)\phi_Y(\omega)$$
it is known that the characteristic function of a Gaussian density is
$$\phi_j(\omega)=e^{i\mu_j-0.5\omega^2\sigma^2_j}$$
So if $X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$
$$\phi_Z(\omega)=e^{i(\mu_X+\mu_Y)-0.5\omega^2(\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y)}$$
which implies $Z \sim N(\mu_X+\mu_Y,\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y)$.
So the pdf of $Z=X+Y$ is
$$f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y)}}e^{-\frac{(z-(\mu_X+\mu_Y))^2}{2(\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y)}}$$

Comment: Where is the $PDF$ of R.V $Z$ here? Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @Ameer786 Are you familiar with the PDF of $\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$? Here $\mu=\mu_X+\mu_Y$ and $\sigma^2=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2$.

Comment: Sure. I got your point. Thanks

Comment: @Ameer786 specified in the answer.

Comment: @Ameer786 upvote if you like the answer please

Comment: @Snoop I haven't reached 15 reputation yet, so I am unable to vote, but I did accepted your answer as it helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want "the sum of two independent Gaussian random variables is also a Gaussian random variable". This is a well-known result, and it's explained brilliantly on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/65871/538579). You will have to adapt the argument because your variables don't have mean zero, but this should be a minor detail.